# s3 amazon url redirect to download page

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

I am trying to build a small plugin for wordpress which takes the url in a shortcode and redirect it to download page and download the file after 2 seconds. I have set s3 bucket permissions as private and setup policy to access my current domain. Now the problem is that when i use a normal anchor text on the website it let me download the file. But using shortcode it says permission denied

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>69F2DE3C8C3ADC79</RequestId>
<HostId>
pOY7yAtY+o2d+0IFd1zJKyJUGfK3fvOig58lU7heJcR/CyF2Xdxa5VXGy2ZcRTf9g0iyVAMNpKA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

But its working without redirect using anchor text. Here is the code for meta refresh.

```
if(isset($_POST['file_id'])){
    $fullurl = $_POST['file_id'];
}
header("Content-type:application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.$fullurl.'");
readfile($fullurl);
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2;url='.$fullurl.'">
```

Comment: What's going on with these dots and single quotes?  `"2;url='.$fullurl.'"` seems like it should be more like `"2;url='$fullurl'"` or even `"2;url=$fullurl"`.